# динамическое обновление контента по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

есть скрипт который добавляет в БД и выводит новые записи.

1) Возможно ли на этом примере сделать, что бы по нажатию на кнопку во всех обновлялся контент в браузере, а не только того кто нажал?

2) Возможно ли это сделать не посылая бесконечные запросы в БД?

3) *setTimeout* запускает один раз скрипт, как его запускать для всех когда один из пользователей добавляет в БД?

//вывод всех записей

```
  function show() {
        if (inProcess) return;
        inProcess = true;
            $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url: "get_data.php", 
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
            inProcess = false;
            $("#content").html(html);
          }
        });
      }
```

// добалвение в БД

```
$(document).on('click', '#but', function(){
            var text= $('#text').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"insert.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{'text':text},
                success:function(res)
                {   
                setTimeout(show, 3000);     
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: Тут уже не AJAX нужен, а Websocket

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, на многих хостингах проекты с вебсокетами будут работать? их надо будет стартовать что бы запустить? php + вебсокеты это еще те танцы с бубном

Comment: Честно сказать, даже не знаю, не работал с сокетами, но задача явно для них.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, уже смотрел в их сторону, и есть свои нюансы, запускаются они с командной строки, переодически через вермя они закрываются, не каждый хостинг даст возможность с ними работать, и самое сладкое, а как его запустить на хостинге, тоже через командную строку?:)